# Issue with adding an NSManagedObject array to pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am having a pickerview whose data I was populating like so in the pickerview `didSelectRow`...

```
myTextField.text = self.myArray[row]
```

Initially `myArray` was of type string. So things were working fine. But now `myArray` is of type `NSManagedObject`. So it is not accepting. Any idea as to how this issue can be addressed..?

**EDIT:** This is how I am accessing the array from picker view

```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if self.appDelegate.commonProductCategArray.count == 0 {
                // An alert message shown here.
        } else {

            let person = self.appDelegate.commonProductCategArray[row]

            categListTextField.text = person.value(forKey: "categoryName") as? String

        }
    }
```

Here, `commonProductCategoryArray` gets its value from another view controller at the time of adding a record to database like so..

```
 try managedContext.save()
 self.mangObjArr.append(category as! Category)
 self.appDelegate.commonProductCategArray = self.mangObjArr
```

Comment: you are using swift or obj-c

Comment: Try changing to `myTextField.text = self.myArray[row] as? String`

Comment: @Subhajit Halder I'm using swift

Comment: NSManagedObject contains string to show in pickerview ? , then it is simple  myTextField.text = (self.myArray[row]  as! YourClass).yourPropery

Comment: @Badhan Ganesh Doing that gives the warning that cast from the NSManagedObject to unrelated type String always fails..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picker View only display `String` in its component labels so you need to fetch the String from `NSManagedObject`.

`textfield.text = managedObject.value(forKeyPath: "keyName") as? String`

According to apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject

In some respects, an NSManagedObject acts like a dictionary—it is a generic container object that efficiently provides storage for the properties defined by its associated NSEntityDescription object.

So you can fetch a value from its keyPath.

**EDIT:**
You are fetching the data which is correct. Hence it shows in `textfield` but you are forgetting to update it in picker views title.

To do that implement:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
       if !self.appDelegate.commonProductCategArray.isEmpty {
            let person = self.appDelegate.commonProductCategArray[row]
            return person.value(forKey: "categoryName") as? String
       }
       return ""
}
```

Comment: Ok @Subhajit Halder..any help on how that can be done...?

Comment: ..a wierd problem is now arising..:) Say my array has an element called 'test' then when I go to the picker view it just shows a '?' sign. But when I move the cursor over it, then 'test' itself is displayed in the required textfield. Why could this be so...?

Comment: can you put the sample code here or in a demo github project, then I can check and edit it. It would be far more easier

Comment: what you are doing is you are fetching the value from the array in did select row and not setting the datasource. Check my edited answer in few min

Comment: Ok, @Subhajit Halder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155234/discussion-between-subhajit-halder-and-user-bw).

Comment: No problem, my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

First question arise here is how you are showing data in `PickerView` if you don't know how to fetch string value from `PickerView`

However it is as simple as fetching data from normal string array

Suppose you are showing `Person` Class object in picker view with `name` property

as each and every `NSManagedObject`  subclass contains properties **you have define while creating a schema**

your array like

```
var array = [NSManagedObject]()
```

You just need to parse it with correct way

```
(array.first as! Person).name
```

You got value !!!